# Cross Play Query

Tags: qsqlquery

I am trying to find the following variations. I have 10 games and individual ids associated to each game. I need to figure out the following:

1. distinct count of all who played all 10 games
2. same but for 9 games
3. etc

The closest formula I came up with:

```
SELECT distinct player_id

FROM ticket

WHERE game_code IN ('17','16') AND  


create_date  BETWEEN  '2018-05-01'

AND '2018-05-31'
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```